# Can reference or iterator invalidation happen with std::pair

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose I have a pair like this:

```
std::pair<std::vector<int>, int> p;
```

And I get a reference to both of these elements like so:

```
auto& firstVect = p.first;
auto& secondNumber = p.second;
```

In case a reallocation happens in the vector by calling for example:

```
firstVect.emplace_back(someNumber);
```

Will this invalidate the `firstVect` reference?
I found information on when invalidation happens for the STL collections, but I cannot find any information on pairs.
I know a reallocation invalidates all references/iterators for a vector, but when a vector is inside a pair like in my case, will the reference be preserved?

I'm on C++17

Comment: Neither reference invalidation will happen.

Comment: adding to the vector may invalidate iterators to elements in it, but the reference to the vector itself won't change or become invalid.  Only if the pair that owns the vector goes out of scope will it be destroyed.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/j3TsW7zvW

Comment: [improved demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ebs5Ks8Tx)

Answer (score 2):

> I know a reallocation invalidates all references/iterators for a vector

A reallocation by the vector invalidates all references, pointers and iterators to *elements* of the vector. The vector itself does not cease to exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this invalidate the `firstVect` reference?

No, it will not. A reference to the `vector` itself remains valid for as long as that `vector` lives.

If the life of the `pair` ends, only then will the reference to the `vector` become "dangling" (invalid).